# change color in ggplot bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart

I am still new to r and was hoping for help on one of my plots. I am trying to add some color to this chart was looking for help doing so.[image: my plot] I believe the image should be included and any tips would be helpful. I'm not looking for anything specific but any advice for how to color the bars or outline them, or even color the background. Thanks for any help!

CODE:

```
 WorldCupMatches %>%
   filter(Year == "2014", Home.Team.Name %in% top10teams_in_order) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = Home.Team.Name, y = Home.Team.Goals)) +
   geom_col()
```

Comment: Does this question help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50380819/create-barplots-in-ggplot2-filled-with-flags-or-images

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have specific colors in mind check the `RColorBrewer` package.  It has many sets of colors that are safe for a color blind audience.

```
library(RColorBrewer)

 WorldCupMatches %>%
   filter(Year == "2014", Home.Team.Name %in% top10teams_in_order) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = Home.Team.Name, y = Home.Team.Goals)) +
   geom_col(fill = brewer.pal(10,"Set3")) + # 10 colors one for each bar
   theme_bw() + # set general look
   theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_blank()) # remove horizontal gridlines
```

If you want to draw attention to one bar you can choose specific colors like this

```
# 7 gray, then 1 red, then 2 gray
geom_col(fill = c(rep("gray", 7), "red", rep("gray", 2))) +
```

Comment: @itsMelnMiami  awesome thank you, i had to play with it a little but that helped greatly

Comment: Welcome.  If it solves it, click the green check next to the answer to mark it as a solution.